# html5 / jquery - click event not registering for html button tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html, webforms

I am trying to validate a form, but I can't get any code to execute when my button is clicked. Here's my code:

```
<div id="vehicle_form">
    <form method="post" name="emailForm" action="">
    <input class="dField" id="dfEmail" type="email" name="email" value="Email" onfocus="clearInput(this);" onblur="restoreInput(this)"><br/>
    <input class="dField" id="dfName" type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name" onfocus="clearInput(this);" onblur="restoreInput(this)"><br/>
    <input class="dField" id="dfLast" type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name" onfocus="clearInput(this);" onblur="restoreInput(this)"><br/>
    <button type="button" id="dSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

$('#dSubmit').click(function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that your jQuery is wrapped in a `<script>` tag, and ensure that the function is being loaded, perhaps by a `$(document).ready()` function, as shown below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Your Click event
    $('#dSubmit').click(function(){
        console.log('click');
    });

});
</script>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6C4W/)

Comment: Ah - that was the problem. It was inside a script tag but not inside document ready.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the code stays wrong. A form can be often submitted by hitting enter inside of a textfield. If you want to make it right you should use the submit event.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#vehicle_form > form').submit(function(){
        console.log('submit');
    });
});
</script>
```